# how to get xpath preceding-sibling working for this table

Tags: xpath

I have a table where I need to find if the checkbox corresponding to a cell is checked or not, see for example, I need to find out if the checkbox id=830 which is a sibling of DeviceHelp is checked or not.

Similarly for element Contact, I will have to check whether checkbox id="72" is checked / unchecked

And I can only rely on the text elements (contact, DeviceHelp, etc) to get the checkboxes state and not the checkbox ids which could change.

```
<tr class="row active" style="display: table-row;">
<td>
<input id="72" class="rowcheck" type="checkbox" value="true" name="ModesForUi[0].Allow" categoryid="58" disabled="">
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="ModesForUi[0].Allow">
</td>
<td> Administration - Read </td>
<td>
Contact
<input id="ModesForUi_0__ResourceID" type="hidden" value="72" name="ModesForUi[0].ResourceID">
<input id="ModesForUi_0__ModeID" type="hidden" value="12185" name="ModesForUi[0].ModeID">
</td>
<td> Controls access to Search Contacts link and to view contact details page. Navigate to Menu\Advanced\More </td>
</tr>
<tr class="row active" style="display: table-row;">
<td>
<input id="830" class="rowcheck" type="checkbox" value="true" name="ModesForUi[1].Allow" categoryid="58" disabled="">
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="ModesForUi[1].Allow">
</td>
<td> Administration - Read </td>
<td>
DeviceHelp
<input id="ModesForUi_1__ResourceID" type="hidden" value="830"     name="ModesForUi[1].ResourceID">
<input id="ModesForUi_1__ModeID" type="hidden" value="12186"     name="ModesForUi[1].ModeID">
</td>
<td> Controls access to Help icon displayed next to logout icon and next to the menu.     </td>
</tr>
```

Have tried the following, but I am not getting the checkbox value

```
"ancestor::td[1]/input[1]/preceding-sibling::td[normalize-space(text())='DeviceHelp']")
```

And

```
//tr[position()>1]/td[normalize-space(text())='DeviceHelp*']/parent::td/preceding-sibling::td/input@value
```

Please xpath experts could you shine some light on what is wrong with the paths above and how to get to the checkbox ?

Thanks!

Comment: You missed to point out what exactly you want selected/produced by the evaluation of the XPAth expression (which node). Please, *edit* the question and specify this missing and important information.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you're trying to get here...

Try this for Device Help:

```
/root/tr/td[normalize-space(text())='DeviceHelp']/../td[1]/input[1]/@value
```

And this for Contact:

```
/root/tr/td[normalize-space(text())='Contact']/../td[1]/input[1]/@value
```

"root" is just whatever node you're starting from, I added that to test locally, as the XML snippet isn't complete.

**EDIT**

Try this:

```
//tr/td[normalize-space(text())='DeviceHelp']/../td[1]/input[1]/@value

//tr/td[normalize-space(text())='Contact']/../td[1]/input[1]/@value
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @JWiley, but I couldn't make that work  
I have tried  many variations, each of those errors
  
  Unable to find xpath "/table/tbody/tr/td[normalize-space(text())='Contact']/../td[1]/input[1]/@value" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)

Unable to find xpath "/table/tbody/tr/td[normalize-space(text())='Contact']" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)

  Unable to find xpath "td[starts-with(.,'Contact')]" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
  
  Unable to find xpath "td[normalize-space(text())='*Contact*']" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)

Comment: It worked for me, but one thing you have to note is that XPath only works on valid xmls, what you posted isn't a valid xml. I added the <root> tags around your block, and finished out the unclosed <input> nodes.

Comment: It was in a proper table, I only pasted a few rows here. Would your solution work on @ http://www.bit-101.com/xpath/

Comment: OK, after your EDIT, I have some result now, will try to work with that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It did, thanks! I cannot vote you as yet as I am very new here.